# How do I disable Transparent Hugepages for Docker for Mac/Windows (Native)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, huge-pages

Transparent Huge Pages is required to be disabled for the TokuDB engine and for Redis. With docker-toolbox, I could just `docker-machine ssh` into the host and disable it. I no longer have access to the host OS, so how do I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this with a privileged container in Docker For Mac/Windows. You can do it like this:

```
docker run -ti --privileged ubuntu /bin/bash
echo never | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

I ended up creating an image for this and made redis/mariadb include it under depends_on in my docker-compose.yml file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

where docker-entrypoint.sh has:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo never | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never | tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

Comment: Running a container as privileged allows the container to access the host and isn't generally a good idea for security reasons. There is a post here about how to log into the VM in Docker for Mac, but it seems a bit of a hack:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-mac-how-to-set-host-settings-sysctl-etc/11168
I'm not aware of an official way of doing this yet.

Comment: What is the advantage (if any) of using the `echo ... | tee <file>` pattern over simply `echo ... > <file>` ?

Comment: @cueedee tee is generally used when writing to the file requires sudo. So I am not sure there is a benefit in that case (without sudo)

Answer (score 2):

An even easier solution is to create file **profile** with content

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled 
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

and add following line to **Dockerfile**

```
COPY profile /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

Comment: do you mean that the image generated by this dockerfile the one used as the docker_compose depends_on?